# How to remove stripped screw from a tight& far spot?

Tags: screws

[image: stripped screw]

I tried using a screwdriver and it didn’t work. The Ryobi drill that I used does not have a Philips screw head can reach to the stripped screw.
So I am stuck on how to get it removed since it is in a tight and far spot

Comment: Can you work from the other end?  If not a trip to your favourite toy(tool) store is in your near future.  Maybe a #4 philips or a large enough slot might grab onto it.

Comment: Worst case, you reach in there with a die grinder and obliterate the screw head. Once the thing is disassembled, then you use some pliers to remove what's left sticking out of the other piece or curse me when you discover that there's not enough for pliers to grab.

Comment: It’s not clear what kind of structure that is, but maybe you could try hammering a Phillips screwdriver into the mess to reinstate the grip enough to turn. Failing that, you’re drilling out the head.

Comment: Can you try a Robertson bit?